# Why is this javascript loop printing out numbers instead of Options?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-select

```
function createShiftsForm(day){
    document.getElementById("shifts").innerHTML += day + ' morn: <select name="' + day + 'm"><option value="0" selected>0</option>';
    for (i=1; i <= 20; i++){
    document.getElementById("shifts").innerHTML += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}
    document.getElementById("shifts").innerHTML += '</select>';


}
```

When it prints out it prints all 21 numbers but only the number 0 is printed as an option for the selector.

Comment: Because the value you pass to `innerHTML` has to be a valid HTML fragment. And `<select><option</option>` isn't.

Comment: Appending to @FelixKling's comment, you should build a string of what you want to add first, and **THEN** add it to `innerHTML`.

Comment: See all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9704872/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064000/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10115711/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16073093/218196

Comment: Duplicate of [innerHTML adds text but not html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16073106/218196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string that you pass to the innerHTML is not valid(you do it step-by-step, so select element doesn't have a closing tag).

```
function createShiftsForm(day){
    var container = day + ' morn: <select name="' + day + 'm"><option    value="0" selected>0</option>';
    for (i=1; i <= 20; i++){
        container += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    container += '</select>';
    document.getElementById("shifts").innerHTML = container;
}
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is almost always useless.

Comment: Between Felix's explanation and your code. I think I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Felix Kling : At first I write solution and only after that explanation :)